# passing data to noir views - Clojure

Tags: clojure, compojure, noir

I'm working with [Noir](http://www.webnoir.org/) and I can't figure out how to pass information to the `views`.
Right now I have a `ref` in `proj.core/my-ref` which is updated in a worker thread.
I need to access the `ref`'s value from a view created via `defpage` located at `proj.views.my-view`.

What would be the idiomatic way of sharing this `ref`?
I was thinking of passing it in a closure somehow but I don't see how that would work with the way noir pulls in the views

#### ie

```
(noir.server/load-views-ns 'proj.views)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the ref to it's own namespace and then just require proj.core in your proj.views, like:

```
(ns proj.views
 (:require proj.model))

(defpage "/foo" [] (@proj.model/my-ref)
```

Comment: push the ref down into its own namespace, e.g. `proj.model`.

Comment: Is there a guarantee that if I require a `ns` from 2 separate places, it will not `:reload-all`? Is it 100% that it will be the same instance?

Comment: @ilia choly, in my experience, it will be the same instance.

Comment: Looks good +1. Someone want to post an answer or just edit @dAni's so I can accept?